# Git when merging branches user is set to = sign instead of current user

Tags: git, gitkraken

This is the result after merging in gitkraken/git bash:

[image: = sign in account instead of real account]

When I merge any branch to master (Or any other branch) my account is not being used. But when I do normal commits it will as expected.

I also used git bash to merge, same result. Does this have anything todo with having 2 accounts on gitkraken? that it's confused which account to merge with and making it like this?

Thanks in regards for helping me out.

Comment: What does the actual author info show when you run `git log` on your branch, after making your commit?  Is it messed up there two?  Maybe this is a Git Kraken problem, not a Git problem.

Comment: Can you try setting this locally for your repository `git config user.name "Your Name"`
`git config user.email "you@example.com"`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Git log shows Author: = <=> While my Commits say: gerben <gerben@x.com> which is good.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna This fixed the issue, but why was this an issue anyways? I really wanna know.

Comment: Did you run `git config user.name = "My Name"`?

Comment: From my experience which was a tiresome fun way to learn, when you use multiple accounts with different repo's, you'll have to configure `user name`, `email` and `GitHub token`. Also, generate a separate `ssh key` for every account, you're using, another thing what I do is modify, the config file per repo and add the user name and config, it's easier that way.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I manage my repo's

In my `.git/config` file

```
[user]
        name = my_name_goes_here
        email = my_email_goes_here
```

Doing this, I don't have to run

```
git config user.name "Your Name" git config user.email "you@example.com"
```

Answer (score -1):

As @KedarnagMukanahallipatna said setting the name and mail *again*, as I have already set it multiple times with

```
git config user.name "Your Name" git config user.email "you@example.com"
```

Fixed the issue. Thanks @KedarnagMukanahallipatna